# Class not found in php script

Tags: php

I have a path in my Laravel project (app/data/report) with 2 files: `refresh_numbers.php''' and '''numbers_temp.php`

I'm trying to run refresh numbers as a way to run one function within numbers_temp like so:

refresh_numbers.php

```
<?php
    require 'Numbers_temp.php';


    echo "Beginning \n\n";
    Numbers_temp::refresh();
    echo "\n Finished \n";

    ?>
```

Numbers_temp.php

```
<?php
namespace app/data/report;
class Numbers_temp
  {
     function refresh()
    {

        $sql = "select C,S,P,Q FROM data";
        $result_set = DB::runQuery_simple($sql);
        $log = "";
        foreach ($result_set as $row) {
            $log .= "EXECUTING: $sql -- ";
            $res = $this->add_quota($row['S'], $row['P'], $row['Q'], $row['C']);
            $log .= "$res \n";
        }
        return $log;
    }

  }
```

But when I run refresh_numbers.php I get an error on line 6 that Class Numbers_temp can't be found?

Comment: You shouldn't mix lower and upper case differently (`Numbers_temp` vs `numbers_temp`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just doesn't know about the namespace. Add a use statement:

`use app\data\report\Numbers_temp;`

Comment: ok when I added that I get the same error but instead of saying 'Class Numbers_temp' not found it now says ' Class 'app\data\report\Numbers_temp' not found'

Comment: change `require` to `require_once` - if it fails, you got the path to the file wrong

Comment: ok when I took Namespace out of the numbers_temp file it worked

Comment: well thats one way of doing it.

Comment: What I mean is, none of the other solutions did anything but when I removed that to test it, it worked but then it fails on another included class. So I'm trying to see if there's an issue with how that file is namespaced

Comment: Oh! You've screwed your namespace up! Use BACKslashes! you have `app/data/report`

Comment: Ok I think that got it! Thanks